# Map class does not work as supposed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have this map class [1] where the goal is just to read and write the content in the same format. The input data is this [2], and it is going to be processed by the map class. I want that this map class does not do any transformation of the data and just outputs the input data. Unfortunately, I get this error [3], and I don't understand where the map class is wrong. Any help to fix the map class?

[1] My map class (now it is corrected).

```
    /** Identity mapper set by the user. */
public static class MyFullyIndentityMapper
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private Text word = new Text();
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, new IntWritable(Integer.valueOf(itr.nextToken())));
        }
    }

    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);
        try {
            while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
                System.out.println("Key ( " + context.getCurrentKey().getClass().getName() + " ): " + context.getCurrentKey()
                        + " Value (" + context.getCurrentValue().getClass().getName() + "): " + context.getCurrentValue());
                map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
            }
        } finally {
            cleanup(context);
        }
    }
}
```

[2] Input data

```
B   1
C   1
I   1
O   1
C   1
E   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
```

[3] Error that I get during the execution of the map class.

```
Key ( org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable ): 0 Value (org.apache.hadoop.io.Text): B
2015-10-11 11:59:54,680 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples.MyWordCount$MyFullyIndentityMapper.map(MyWordCount.java:93)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.examples.MyWordCount$MyFullyIndentityMapper.run(MyWordCount.java:104)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

[4] My Reduce class

```
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        Iterator iter = values.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iter.next());
        }
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            System.out.println(" - key ( " + key.getClass().toString() + "): " + key.toString()
                    + " value ( " + val.getClass().toString() + " ): " + val.toString());
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }

    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Output dir: " + context.getConfiguration().get("mapred.output.dir"));
        System.out.println("Partitioner class: " + context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.partitioner.class"));
        try {
            while (context.nextKey()) {
                System.out.println("Key: " + context.getCurrentKey());
                reduce(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getValues(), context);
            }
        } finally {
            cleanup(context);
        }
    }
}
```

[5] Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(new Configuration(), args);

    String[] otherArgs = parser.getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: wordcount [<in>...] <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    // first map tasks
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(MyWordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setJarByClass(MyWordCount.class);
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    Path[] inputPaths = new Path[otherArgs.length-1];
    for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) { inputPaths[i] = new Path(otherArgs[i]); }
    Path outputPath =  new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, inputPaths);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, outputPath);

    // launch the job directly
    Job job = new Job(conf, conf.getJobName());
    job.setJarByClass(MyWordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MyFullyIndentityMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job.setPartitionerClass(HashPartitioner.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    System.exit(0);
}
```

[6] Here are the imports that I use, just in case it is necessary

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.HashPartitioner;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
```

Comment: Why is your map key an Object. Shouldn't be longwritable?

Comment: I thought that the key was the offset of the file and the value the line of the file (e.g. B 1). The key is an Object because I am ignoring it.

Comment: Yes the key is offset but the recordreader sends that key as longwritable and your mapper key should be expecting a longwritable.. If you dont want to pass that to the map output you could just ignore it or use NullWritable. can you try giving it as LongWritable?

Comment: @VigneshI I think both Object and Longwritable can be used and it is not going to make any differnece

Comment: @madhu Agree Thanks. just checked the error log it got the correct key(0) and value pair(B).

Comment: I was passing the wrong input. I have fixed the map class and it works.  Now I have a problem in the reduce class. The addition is not being made. I have put the correct map class and the reduce class in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your input file again.

```
Key ( org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable ): 0 Value (org.apache.hadoop.io.Text): B
```

From the above line it is understood that context is fetching your value as just `B` and not as `B 1`.
And therefore when we try to fetch the next token from the string tokenizer and set it in val part it throws an error.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Why I am just getting `B` and not `B  1`?

Comment: Is it because the org.apache.hadoop.io.Text just cares with words and not lines of text?

Comment: I have also another problem that is related to this one. I have added in the original post the reduce class, and the reducers just does not add the values. It just takes the input and put it in the output. The addition is not being made. I am not understanding what is happening. How can I debug this?

Comment: Yes it is. I was passing the wrong input data, that is why the values `1` do not exist. Now I am looking to the reducer. The addition is not being made. I am trying to trace the my reduce class with `System.out.println`. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: In my case, it looks that in the reduce side, the values are not passing. I try to print the values and it does not print something.

Comment: The `main` class is in the original post.  It looks that the `reduce` call is invoking `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer#reduce` and not my `reduce` function, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, I am right. The `reduce` call is invoking `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer#reduce` and not my `reduce` function. But why?

Comment: public static class MyReducer extends Reducer {.... In this first line of your reducer there is no input and output key value pairs

Comment: It should be... public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>

Comment: I have put it now, but the problem remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92032/discussion-between-user3240152-and-madhu).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The signature must be public void reduce(Text key, Iterable values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {...}